# jQuery:How to remove all the delegate events

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my program, I use the `body` to delegate all events in the web page.And How I can remove that?  Here is  my code, Thanks .

```
jQuery(function ($) {

  $("body").on("mouseenter.noteEvent", "*", function (event) {
        //doSomeThing();
    });

  $("body").on("mouseleave.noteEvent", "*", function (event) {
        //doSomeThing();
    });

 $("body").on("click.noteEvent", "*", function (event) {
        //doSomeThing();
    });

});
```

and the remove event function,But it failed, have any suggestions?

```
 var removeEvent = function(){

    jQuery("body").off(".noteEvent", "*"); // '*' or '**' ?
    //jQuery("body").off(".noteEvent", "**"); 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use following to remove the event:

```
$("body").off("mouseenter.noteEvent");
```

Or if you use:

```
$("body").off("mouseenter");
```

Then all the `mouseenter` events will be removed. also you may use:

```
// Remove all event handlers from all paragraphs:
$("p").off();

// Remove all delegated mouseenter handlers from all paragraphs:
$("p").off("mouseenter", "**");

// Remove event handlers in the ".noteEvent" namespace
$("body").off(".noteEvent");
```

Read more on [jQuery Site](http://api.jquery.com/off/).

Answer (score 0):

When unbinding all delegated event handlers by their namespace, you only need do:

```
jQuery("body").off(".noteEvent"); // only specify the namespace.
```